# Microsoft Bot emulator with luis-endpoint issue

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am new to bot framework and am building a bot using microsoft.
It is working fine when i create and run locally.

When i try integrating with Luis it throws errors in emulator:

[image]

and

[image]

I have used the appid and apikey all same as in Luis portal.

Endpoint url is also exactly the same.
Earlier when i was using :
endpoint: `https://${ process.env.LuisAPIHostName }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`

It was throwing error directly.

But when i use direct url: ----cognitiveservices.azure.com(this is my url)
[image]

It does not throw error on npm start.
But after first few commands it stops.
When i click on Luis trace i see errors as above.

But what surprises me is in emulator it shows the predictions for the entities.
If there is issue with endpoint, how is it doing the prediciton?

Comment: you need to append extra parameters in the Luis API, then only it will work

Comment: Also just confirm the endpoint and keys that you are using in luis application and once publish the Luis app in prod or stag env you will get publish URL with a search query parameter.